# How to Union the results of sp_Help stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using the `sp_help` stored procedure to see all the database objects for a given database in SQL Server. However, I have 92 databases and each time I run this stored proc I have to manually copy & paste the result set into an Excel sheet for each database. I will later take all the data for each database and make a pivot table to summarize the information regarding all the databases.

Is there any way to use `sp_help` for all 92 databases so I can just copy & paste all of the results at once into an Excel sheet? This would save me A LOT of time.

Also, in the result set of `sp_help`, I want the name of the database as the first column in addition to the "Name, Owner, and ObjectType" columns that `sp_help` stored proc. returns.

So, something like below but also the database name as a column in addition to the 3 columns that `sp_help` returns data for:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
EXEC sp_help;  
GO

UNION ALL

USE WineDB;  
GO  
EXEC sp_help ;  
GO

.... and so on for all 92 databases
```

I am new to looking at this information for databases, so I am assuming the `sp_help` stored procedure returns all of the objects in a database without leaving anything out? Is it 100% accurate?

I was also able to make the below query which seems to give the same information as `sp_help` but I'm not sure if it leaves anything out?

```
USE MyDB;

DECLARE @DATABASE_NAME SYSNAME;
SET @DATABASE_NAME = 'MyDB';

SELECT
   DB_NAME() AS 'Database_Name'
  ,OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS 'Name'
  ,s.name AS 'Owner'
  ,REPLACE(LOWER(o.type_desc), '_', ' ') AS 'Object_Type'
FROM 
  sys.all_objects AS o
INNER JOIN
  sys.schemas AS s 
ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @DanGuzman SQL Server 2014

Comment: `sp_help` looks like it returns too much rather than too little. I don't see the value of returning all the system procs for every database. You should likely just construct your own query that returns what you care about - and maybe use [`sp_ineachdb`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql) to run that in each DB and insert to a temp table

Comment: Doing a database migration so we need all the information we can get, this is my first time doing a database migration so I don't want to leave anything out.

Comment: Doing what kind of database migration? Can you not use a process that copies the whole database? e.g. Database restore?

Comment: From SQL Server On-Premises to SQL Server Managed Instance. We do plan on doing that, but I was tasked by my senior database engineer to do this specific task so if someone could help me, I'd greatly appreciate it. I don't have the option to decline work handed down to me by my seniors.

Comment: First of all what all information you need about table.May be you explore Select * from information_schema_tables.There is no in built thing where you can copy from all 92 databases.You have to write query suiting your requirement.First share what is the data structure ?